# Translate short script from JavaScript to Lua

Tags: javascript, lua, lua-4.0

I have the following JS script that is known to work correctly and produces the correct value of 12 for the **restrictCount** value.

```js
var radius = 4
var gnWide = radius * 2 - 1;
var gnHigh = radius * 2 - 1;
var restrictTable = [];
var restrictCount = 0;
var gride = [];
var grido = [];

for (var y = 0; y < gnHigh; y++) {
    restrictTable[y] = [];
    for (var x = 0; x < gnWide; x++) {
        restrictTable[y][x] = 0;
    }
}

for (var y = 0; y < gnHigh; y++) {
    gride[y] = [];
    grido[y] = [];
    for (var x = 0; x < radius; x++) {
        gride[y][x] = 0;
        grido[y][x] = 0;
    }
}

function makeHexagon() {
    var cne = Math.ceil(radius/2) - radius%2;
    for (var y = 0; y < gnHigh; y++) {
        for (var x = 0; x < cne; x++) {
            gride[y][x] = 1;
            gride[y][radius-x-1] = 1;
        }
        if (y < radius-1)
            cne--;
        else if (y > radius-1-radius%2)
            cne++;
    }
    cne = Math.ceil(radius/2) - radius%2 - 1;
    for (var y = 0; y < gnHigh; y++) {
        for (var x = 0; x < cne; x++) {
            grido[y][x] = 1;
            grido[y][radius-x-2] = 1;
        }
        if (y < radius-1-radius%2)
            cne--;
        else if (y > radius-2)
            cne++;
    }
}

function combineTables() {
    for (var y = 0; y < gnHigh; y++) {
        for (var x = 0; x < gnHigh; x++) {
            if (x%2 == 0) {
                var value = gride[y][x/2]
                restrictTable[y][x] = value
                restrictCount += value
            } else {
                var value = grido[y][Math.floor(x/2)]
                restrictTable[y][x] = value
                restrictCount += value
            }
        }
    }
}

makeHexagon()
combineTables()
alert(restrictCount)
```

I need this translated into Lua 4 code. However, the table indices are confusing me. In JS tables start with 0. In Lua they start with 1. They are mixed frequently in this code and it's throwing me off. Here's my attempt which results in 11 instead of 12:

```lua
radius = 4
gnWide = radius * 2 - 1
gnHigh = radius * 2 - 1
restrictTable = {}
restrictCount = 0
gride = {}
grido = {}

for y = 1, gnHigh do
    restrictTable[y] = {}
    for x = 1, gnWide do
        restrictTable[y][x] = 0
    end
end

for y = 1, gnWide do
    gride[y] = {}
    grido[y] = {}
    for x = 1, radius do
        gride[y][x] = 0
        grido[y][x] = 0
    end
end

function makeHexagon()
    cne = ceil(radius/2) - mod(radius,2)
    for y = 1, gnHigh do
        for x = 1, cne do
            gride[y][x] = 1
            gride[y][radius-x] = 1
        end
        if (y < radius) then
            cne = cne - 1
        elseif (y > radius-mod(radius,2)) then
            cne = cne + 1
        end
    end
    cne = ceil(radius/2) - mod(radius,2) - 1
    for y = 1, gnHigh do
        for x = 1, cne do
            grido[y][x] = 1
            grido[y][radius-x-1] = 1
        end
        if (y < radius-mod(radius,2)) then
            cne = cne - 1
        elseif (y > radius-1) then
            cne = cne + 1
        end
    end
end

function combineTables()
    for y = 1, gnHigh do
        for x = 1, gnWide do
            if (mod(x,2) == 1) then
                local value = gride[y][ceil(x/2)]
                restrictTable[y][x] = value
                restrictCount = restrictCount + value
            else
                local value = grido[y][x/2]
                restrictTable[y][x] = value
                restrictCount = restrictCount + value
            end
        end
    end
end

makeHexagon()
combineTables()
print(restrictCount)
```

Can someone double check my code? I can't find the mistake. Thanks!

Comment: Try to keep the algorithm exactly the same while translating from JS to Lua, and then only add `+1` in every table access, e.g., `gride[y+1][x+1]`. This way you should easily get a correct translation. You can refactor from there if you like.

Comment: Your second loop uses `gnWide` but the original uses `gnHigh` just for the record.

Comment: You don't even need top add `+1`. You can use `0` as an index in Lua tables. Just don't blindly use those tables with the standard Lua library.

Comment: @lhf I used your advice and at least found the error I made. Thanks!